# Know the event receive by Youtube Push Notificationy - PubSubHubbub

Tags: youtube, websub

I use PubSubHubbub to receive notifications of new videos on Youtube :https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/push_notifications

It works very well.
However, when I edit the title of a video or its description, an event is sent to my Webhook.

How do I know if the event I received is a new video or an edited video?

I thought of the solution of saving video IDs as I go, but I find this solution not at all suitable.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

The Id of the video doesn't change when it's updated so you can check if the video exist on your database if it's exist that's mean  update and then update the video on database else it's a new video